# Using multiple select statements inside single query and display the results as a new rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

I want to create a query which returns the sum of certain select statement parameters within the query and create a new result table with new rows which is the results derived from select statements as below.

This is my table.

[image]

I want the result to be like below where Col4 is the result of a select statement with row 2, 3 and 5 and column 5 is the result of the calculation on the col values as below

[image]

and the result will look like this below. Is that possible to do in MS SQL SERVER.
[image]

Comment: What is the logic for combining rows?

Comment: Rows are combined into groups as per criteria. Say row 112, 113 and 115 is part of one group. And similarly others also fall into different groups.

Comment: *"as per criteria"* What criteria? Where is it coming from?

Comment: The only question you asked is if this is possible. Yes this is possible. Since you probably need more help than that I would suggest you explain your logic here. You see, the query here is going to be quite simple. But until you can explain how this data is grouped nobody can help you.

Comment: Ok. The thing is there is not fixed logic. For selection one i have to group 3 items from col1 and in another selection I have to group 4 or 1 item from col1. This is not fixed and i have to manually use a select statement for each of the select within the main query. May be the usage of three col1 items in the example is confusing.

Comment: Also i intent to do i by using the where col= 112,113,144 etc

Answer (score 0):

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/87a6f/4)

```
--http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/87a6f/4
--Schema
create  table mytable(col1 int,col2 int,col3 int,col4 int)
insert into mytable values
(111,1,0,4),
(112,3,1,2),
(113,1,2,2),
(114,2,4,3),
(115,3,1,0),
(116,1,0,2),
(117,2,1,0),
(118,4,1,3),
(119,3,2,1)
create table  tabscript (col4 varchar(max),col5 varchar(max))
create table  tabresult(col4 varchar(max),col5 int)


--Put here th scripts you wish to execute

insert into tabscript(col4,col5) values('112,113,115','sum(col2+col3+col4)'),
('115,117,119','sum(col2+col3+col4)'),('114,118,111','sum(col2+col3+col4)')


--Kamel Gazzah
--kamelgazzah@gmail.com
--29/10/2019
declare @script as varchar(max)
declare @sqlCommand as nvarchar(max)
declare @result as int
declare mycursor  cursor for
select concat('select @result=',col5, ' from mytable where col1 in(',col4,')') 
from tabscript 
open mycursor
declare @sql as nvarchar(max)
fetch mycursor into @sqlCommand
while @@fetch_status=0
begin
--print @sql
--print @sqlCommand
exec sp_executesql @sqlCommand,N'@result int output',@result output
insert into tabresult values(@sqlcommand,@result)

fetch mycursor into @sqlCommand
end
close mycursor
deallocate mycursor
go
select * from tabresult
```